# Javascript and XHR server requests

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on a assignment for my JavaScript class and needed some assistance or a direction to get started. It is a very simple program that gets the length and width through user input, then calculates the area and perimeter and displays it in text boxes.

That part was simple enough to do, however we then have to change the program so that it sends the user entered length and width to a node.js express server. The server is supposed to do the calculations with the 2 user entered parameters that are in the url. After the calculations are complete the area and perimeter values are returned in a json object.

Now the 2 problems that I am running into is that I can't send the user input to the express server and I also can't figure out how to catch the returned json object in the original .js file. Below is the main JavaScript file followed by the express server file. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

These were the instructions for the assignment:

- Write a handler to accept requests to the URL "/calc/"
- The URL above should expect 2 URL params, length and width. eg.  http://localhost/calc/?length=1&width=1
- In the body of the handler, calculate the area and perimeter and return them in a JSON object as follows:  { "area": 1, "perimeter": 1 }
- Write another handler that accepts requests to the URL "/", this handler should return the HTML file attached
  -Update the HTML and JS files (attached) to leverage your new application server instead of calculating on the client side.

  ```
  function calculate(){

  // alert statements are great for troublshooting, they let you know where you are in the program.
  console.log('You just clicked the button!');
  alert("This must be a number, not something else");

  /*
  Get a reference to the HTML element with the ID of 'length'.
  Please note, this is a reference to the HTML element, NOT WHAT YOU TYPED IN THE BOX!
  If you need to get what you typed in the box you will nedd to access the element's 'value' attribute, then convert it to a float.
  */
  var length_element = document.getElementById('length');
  var length = parseFloat(length_element.value);

  var width_element = document.getElementById('width');
  var width = parseFloat(width_element.value);


  // Now make an XHR request to your server via the URL below.
  // http://localhost:3000/calc?length=length&width=width
  // Capture the results in the variables below
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/calc/?legnth=" + length + "&width=" + width, true);
  xhttp.send(null);


  // Don't know what to do beyond this part or where to go from here.
  var area =
  var perimeter =



  // If you need to set the 'value' attribute of a text box you can do it like this
  var area_element = document.getElementById('area');
  area_element.value = area;

  var perimeter_element = document.getElementById('perimeter');
  perimeter_element.value = perimeter;

  }
  ```

  Second File

  ```
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();

  var path = require("path");

  app.get('/calc/', function (req, res) {
      var length = req.query.length;
      var width = req.query.width; 
      var area = length*width;
      var perimeter = ((length*2) + (width*2));
      res.send( { "area": area, "perimeter": perimeter });
  });

  app.get('/', function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
      })

  app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
  });
  ```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest for a good reference on `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to read the response off of `xhttp` on `xhttp.onload`. Here's a simple example

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/calc/?legnth=" + length + "&width=" + width, true);
xhttp.send();

xhttp.onload = function (e) {
    var response = xhttp.response;
}
```

You may have to parse your response data depending on what is being sent from the server script.

There are other things like `Content-Type` header `encoding` etc to take care of for a more complete solution, but assuming you need to stick to basic JavaScript you can do away with `JSON.parse` for the moment.